# Merge array of records based on comparing common key

Tags: javascript

I need to merge `count` records based on comparing common `sID` and `nID`. Below are the raw data on which I want to merge records.

So, in the below records for `sID` 2, `nID` 111 and `sID` 2, `nID` 222 there are total four JSON object. In same `sID` and `nID` object there is a value of `ar` and in another object, there is a value of `mr`. So, I need to merge those records into one JSON object.

Basically, the records are vice versa. In one JSON the records will be for `status.count.mr` and in another JSON the records will be for `status.count.ar`. So, that is the reason I need to combine both `status.count.mr` and `status.count.ar` into one object for a specific `sID` of `nID`

```js
const records = [
{division: {name: "AAA", sId: 1, nId: 111}, status: {dates: {nDate: "02-20", dDate: "03-20"}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 0, totalAR: 0, totalEMR: 10, totalMR: 0}}},
{division: {name: "AAA", sId: 1, nId: 222}, status: {dates: {nDate: "02-19", dDate: "03-20"}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 0, totalAR: 0, totalEMR: 10, totalMR: 0}}}
{division: {name: "BBB", sId: 2, nId: 111}, status: {dates: {nDate: "02-20", dDate: "03-20"}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 5, ar: 0, totalAR: 0, totalEMR: 0, totalMR: 9}}}
{division: {name: "BBB", sId: 2, nId: 111}, status: {dates: {nDate: "02-20", dDate: "03-20"}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 2, totalAR: 7, totalEMR: 0, totalMR: 0}}}
{division: {name: "BBB", sId: 2, nId: 222}, status: {dates: {nDate: "02-19", dDate: "03-20"}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 3, ar: 0, totalAR: 0, totalEMR: 0, totalMR: 9}}}
{division: {name: "BBB", sId: 2, nId: 222}, status: {dates: {nDate: "02-19", dDate: "03-20"}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 4, totalAR: 7, totalEMR: 0, totalMR: 0}}}
]
```

For that I have tried below solution.

```js
const mergedMap = new Map();
  for (const record of records) {
    const { sId, nId } = record.division;
    const existingRecord = mergedMap.get(`${sId}-${nId}`);

    if (existingRecord) {
      mergedMap.set(`${sId}-${nId}`, {
        division: existingRecord.division,
        status: {...existingRecord.status, 
          count: {...existingRecord.status.count, ...record.status.count}, 
          dates: {...existingRecord.status.dates, ...record.status.dates},
        },
      });
    } else {
      mergedMap.set(`${sId}-${nId}`, record);
    }
  }
const mergedData = Array.from(mergedMap.values());
```

Result which I need is as below.

```js
const mergedData = [
{division: {name: "AAA", sId: 1, nId: 111}, status: {dates: {...}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 0, totalAR: 0, totalEMR: 10, totalMR: 0}}},
{division: {name: "AAA", sId: 1, nId: 222}, status: {dates: {...}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 0, totalAR: 0, totalEMR: 10, totalMR: 0}}}
{division: {name: "BBB", sId: 2, nId: 111}, status: {dates: {...}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 5, ar: 2, totalAR: 7, totalEMR: 0, totalMR: 9}}}
{division: {name: "BBB", sId: 2, nId: 222}, status: {dates: {...}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 3, ar: 4, totalAR: 7, totalEMR: 0, totalMR: 9}}}
]
```

P.S: From above code snippet I am getting the result without copying the `mr` and `totalMR` values. So the result which I am gettitng is as below

```js
const mergedData = [
{division: {name: "AAA", sId: 1, nId: 111}, status: {dates: {...}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 0, totalAR: 0, totalEMR: 10, totalMR: 0}}},
{division: {name: "AAA", sId: 1, nId: 222}, status: {dates: {...}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 0, totalAR: 0, totalEMR: 10, totalMR: 0}}}
{division: {name: "BBB", sId: 2, nId: 111}, status: {dates: {...}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 2, totalAR: 7, totalEMR: 0, totalMR: 0}}}
{division: {name: "BBB", sId: 2, nId: 222}, status: {dates: {...}, count: {emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 4, totalAR: 7, totalEMR: 0, totalMR: 0}}}
]
```

Comment: What's the actual merging logic you're after and what's wrong with your current output (helps us playing spot-the-difference)? Keep the highest number?

Comment: I need to combine the `count` records ... As the counting of records in the raw data is in the separate json even though the `sID`, `nID`, `nDate` and `dDate` are same. So i need to combine those records which contains same `sID` and `nID`

Comment: You're already combining them though. How do you want to combine them? Add them together, take the max value between all of them, etc.?

Comment: Yes I am combining the records but somehow it is not copying the `mr` and `totalMR` key records. Let me update question that what I am getting after applying the above solution.

Comment: Why should `totalMR` be `9` for the last object for example? What's the logic behind it needing to be `9`? All the objects have a `totalMR` of `0` where `sId` and `nId` is `2`/`222`, so why shouldn't it be `0`?

Comment: As you can observe in the records for `sID` 2 and `nID` 111 there are two JSON object .. In one object there is a counting of `AR` and in another object there is a counting of `mr`. So i need to merge those records into one json object.

Comment: no you are meging two objects into two objects.

Comment: Sorry in above comment consider `sID` 2 , `nid` 111 AND `sID` 2 , `nid` 222

Comment: @TMA Why should `totalMR: 9` from the object with `sId` of `2` and `nId` of `111` appear in the merged object for `sId` of `2` and `nId` of `222`. The `sId` and `nId`s of these are different, so what's the merging logic?

Comment: Hello @NickParsons: I have updated my question as it becomes quit confusing.

Comment: does the same grouped objects (not JSON, which is stringed data) has alwas the same content (like for 2/111)? woult it work, if we take only single object for taking a flat object with all combined values different from zero?

Comment: btw, what if you have a third different `nId` in a same `sId` group?

Comment: I have updated the question by adding actual values on the `status.count` key. If there is a third `nId` for same `sId` then the  `status.count` will also be grouped in that situation.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Except the `status.count` all the content will be same for matching `sId` and `nId`. And basically, the records are vice versa ... So in one JSON the records will be for `status.count.mr` and in another json the records will be for `status.count.ar`. So that is the reason I need to combine both `status.count.mr` and `status.count.ar` into one object for a specific `sId` of `nId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group and then add the counts.

```js
const
    records = [{ division: { name: "AAA", sId: 1, nId: 111 }, status: { dates: { nDate: "02-20", dDate: "03-20" }, count: { emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 0, totalAR: 0, totalEMR: 10, totalMR: 0 } } }, { division: { name: "AAA", sId: 1, nId: 222 }, status: { dates: { nDate: "02-19", dDate: "03-20" }, count: { emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 0, totalAR: 0, totalEMR: 10, totalMR: 0 } } }, { division: { name: "BBB", sId: 2, nId: 111 }, status: { dates: { nDate: "02-20", dDate: "03-20" }, count: { emr: 0, mr: 5, ar: 0, totalAR: 0, totalEMR: 0, totalMR: 9 } } }, { division: { name: "BBB", sId: 2, nId: 111 }, status: { dates: { nDate: "02-20", dDate: "03-20" }, count: { emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 2, totalAR: 7, totalEMR: 0, totalMR: 0 } } }, { division: { name: "BBB", sId: 2, nId: 222 }, status: { dates: { nDate: "02-19", dDate: "03-20" }, count: { emr: 0, mr: 3, ar: 0, totalAR: 0, totalEMR: 0, totalMR: 9 } } }, { division: { name: "BBB", sId: 2, nId: 222 }, status: { dates: { nDate: "02-19", dDate: "03-20" }, count: { emr: 0, mr: 0, ar: 4, totalAR: 7, totalEMR: 0, totalMR: 0 } } }],
    addObject = (a, b) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(a).map(([k, v]) => [k, v + b[k]])),
    grouped = Object
        .values(Object.groupBy(records, ({ division: { sId, nId } }) => sId + '|' + nId))
        .map(data => data.reduce((a, b) => ({
            ...a,
            status: {
               ...a.status, 
                count: addObject(a.status.count, b.status.count)
            }
        })));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer but sorry you did the wrong thing ,I need to copy the records based on the common `sID`  and `nID`. No need to sum the values.

Comment: @TMA, now the original solution with new data set.

Comment: You literally did a magic by utilizing `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries`. Thank you so much for your efforts and utilizing your valuable time to provide the solution. Cheers!